# A python solution of "count and say" from leetcode went wrong

Tags: python

```
class Solution:
    # @param n, an integer
    # @return a string
    def countAndSay(self, n):
        def f(string):
            a = []
            count_1 = 1
            count_2 = 1
            s = string[1:] + 'e'                                    #calculate i from string[1](this is to disregard the case of string[0]), meanwhile add 'e' to notify the end of the string
            for i, j in enumerate(s):

                if j == '1':
                    if string[i] == '1':                            #check whether the last member in string is the same as j
                        count_1 += 1                                #if so, count_1 add 1, save for further list appending
                    else:
                        count_1 = 1                                 #reset the count if last character does not match with j
                        a.append[(str(count_2) + '2')]              

                if j == '2':
                    if string[i] == '2':
                        count_2 += 1
                    else:
                        count_2 = 1
                        a.append[(str(count_1) + '1')]

                if j == 'e':                                         #j=='e' if the iteration reach the end, and it is the right time for adding the final member of the expected list
                    if string[i] == '1':                            
                        a.append[(str(count_1) + '1')]
                    if string[i] == '2':
                        a.append[(str(count_2) + '2')]

                return ''.join(list)

        def seq(n): 
            if n == 1:
                return '1'
            if n == 2:
                return '11'
            if n == 3:
                return '21'
            else:
                return f(seq(n-1))

        return seq(n)
```

This is a solution of a problem from leetcode:
https://leetcode.com/problems/count-and-say/

It notifies me that:

> Runtime Error Message:    Line 17: TypeError:
>   'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '**getitem**'
>
> Last executed input:  4

Line 17 comes as follows:

```
a.append[(str(count_2) + '2')]
```

Please, I am a completely novice and don't know how to solve this problem.
Also, I would like you to improve my code as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: What are you expecting `a.append[(str(count_2) + '2')]` to do, exactly? Perhaps you should read e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: We need to know what you're passing in to `string`, also `return ''.join(list)` should probably be outside the loop in `f()`, where is `list` coming from? There's a lot going on here...

Comment: Where is line 17 in the above code?

Comment: Here is line 17:   a.append[(str(count_2) + '2')]

Comment: I think it is okay for me to use "a.append[(str(count_2) + '2')]", to add element for my list. I will join the members of the list after then to produce the string.

Comment: *"I think it is okay"* - well **clearly** you are wrong, because the Python interpreter is telling you that **doing so is an error**.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is clear, that line 17 should look like

```
a.append(str(count_2) + '2')
```

See [documentation on lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

When you use square brackets (`a.append[key]`) Python will try to call `__getitem__` method on `a.append`

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked.